# Getting error with Page View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I keep getting the following error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The number of view controllers provided (0) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested transition.'

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my `PageViewController` that could be causing this error. Also I tried to follow the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333746/uipageviewcontroller-class-crashing-on-setting-more-than-one-view-controllers). However, the solution didn't help me because I am not sure which piece of my code could be causing the issue.  I am pretty new to Swift, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I figured out that the `setViewController` is causing the issue, and it goes away when deleted. However, why would that cause an issue?
Thanks!

```
    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.pageViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    let allViewControllers = [harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2, harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as! ViewController3, harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController4") as! ViewController4, harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController5") as! ViewController5, harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController6") as! ViewController6, harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController7") as! ViewController7]
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: allViewControllers)
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Comment: You should show your code, it's hard to know what you are doing wrong without knowing what you are doing at all

Comment: @AndréFratelli Ok, I added my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not how the page view controller works. You do not pass multiple view controller but only one, or max two. See the apple docs:

> When defining a page view controller interface, you can provide the content view controllers one at a time (or two at a time, depending upon the spine position and double-sided state) or as-needed using a data source. When providing content view controllers one at a time, you use the setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: method to set the current content view controllers. To support gesture-based navigation, you must provide your view controllers using a data source object.

I assume you want gesture bases navigation, so you will need to implement the page view controller delegate and data source. There are plenty of page view controller tutorials on google.

Comment: So does that mean when using the `setViewControllers` method I only provide one view controller? So for example it would be `self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewController as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil).`

Comment: Yes. And the other ViewController are provided over the implementation of the data source. You just pass the first visible one with setViewController.

Comment: Okay. I set the updated my code. I think that was probably the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only reason you might pass two ViewControllers in an array (to `setViewControllers`) is if you were showing two pages at a time in your `UIPageViewController`. If you're showing one page at a time, then you only pass `setViewControllers` one `UIViewController` at a time, even though you're passing it in an array.

Answer (score 1):

The method set `setViewControllers` expects just the first view controller to be displayed! Try like this:

```
if let firstVC = myViewControllers?.first {
    setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true)
}
```

`myViewControllers` is a property of my `UIPageViewController` subclass!

Hope it works for you!